# Trying to animate a die roll in Java

Tags: java, image, dice

I'm attempting to "animate" a die roll in Java.  I currently have an icon (called "diceImage") set up that, when a button is clicked (called "diceRoll"), updates to a new random image of a die face.  What I would like to do is have it change image (to a random die face) numerous times over a couple of seconds before stopping on a final image.

The problem I have is not with generating a random number, or rolling it numerous times, it's with the updating the image numerous times within a loop.  The code below, which rolls the die 10 times is what I have so far:

```
private void diceRollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        rollDice();
        pause(100);
    }
}
```

This links to the following two methods (the first of which generates the random number, and sets the icon image):

```
private void rollDice() {

    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNumber = r.nextInt(6) + 1;

    diceImage.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Game/Images/Dice " + randomNumber + ".png")));

}
```

The method below is "supposed" to pause the programme briefly between updating the image (this was taken from a programming course I was on where we had to animate an image of a car moving across the screen):

```
private void pause(int sleepTime) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

All this programme seems to do is pause and then print the final dice roll.  It doesn't show any of the "intermediate" faces.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this isn't working?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type is diceImage?

Comment: diceImage is a jLabel

Comment: Why don't you make a BufferedImage and then put that into diceImage? Then update the BufferedImage to a new one to make it change the image rolled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pause() you are using is when u need to animate moving stuff like a car for example , but just changing the icon of a JLabel which is the dice here doesn't need pause ( unless you just want it to be delayed a bit) ...

but anyways , to solve your issue , you need to call repaint() on that JLabel or updateGraphics(). Setting the Icon for the JLabel doesn't make the new Icon get displayed , you just need to repaint() it .

of course like JB Nizet said , for the app not to hang you need to call repaint on a new Thread .Thought you have to learn how to use Thread well cuz it can be very tricky at times .
good luck

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked several times a day. If you sleep in the event dispatch thread, you're preventing it from doing its job: react to events and repaint the screen.

Your animation should be done in another thread. Read the tutorial about [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), and use a Swing Timer.